# Massive database in Firebase have to be cleared, wrong coding to edit the data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry for the title being kinda messy. 
I want to delete all the massive data in my Firebase Realtime DB. But I can't and its a lot..

[image]

and here too.

[image]

[image]

I have to do it 1 by 1, cannot delete all by hover 'player'

Comment: I did. as you can see. it says "Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance
Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime". So I have to 1 by 1. There is no `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete it by doing this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("player").removeValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import an empty file.json inside your database. It will delete every entry.

(Your file.json must have : `{}` at least)